# How to enable SSH on boot in Ubuntu MATE

Tags: openssh

I have installed Ubuntu Mate 16.04.2 LTS on my Pi2 and installed OpenSSH but when the Pi starts/restarts SSH does not automatically turn on.

I've tried `sudo systemct1 enable ssh` but all I get is "Command not found"

I am connecting via wifi from my windows PC, if I enable the service manually I am able to connect without issue, I just can't get it to enable SSH on boot.

I am a newer user so if this is a multi-step process I would appreciate a step by step answer, thank you.

Comment: There too many answer below, but nobody have described that your command was wrong - it should has lowercase `L`, not `1`. The correct command is `sudo systemctl enable ssh` (not `sudo systemct1 enable ssh`).

Answer (score 16):

I think the command you're looking for is:

```
sudo systemctl enable ssh
```

(Note the letter "l" at the end of `systemctl`, rather than the number "1" at the end of `systemct1` as you currently have it in the question.)

Comment: Also, if it does not work, try `sudo systemctl disable ssh.socket`, because even after I enabled ssh, it did not autorun (`systemctl is-enabled ssh` was `enabled`, but `systemctl is-active ssh` was `inactive`) until I manually `sudo systemctl start ssh`. But then I noticed that `ssh.socket` was activated on boot, so I disabled it, and by doing it, ssh autoruned.

Answer (score 9):

I experienced a problem when commands from this topic wouldn't help. I am on Mate 18.04 and I got ssh to work only after I reinstalled openssh-server and run command from topic. So if you experience the same problem, just:

```
sudo apt-get remove openssh-server
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
# I rebooted system after install
sudo systemctl enable ssh
```

Comment: You my friend just made my day! Thank you so much

Comment: This also worked for me on a Ubuntu Mate install on a Raspberry Pi.  Apparently openssh-server is installed by default but no keys are generated so it won't work.  Removing and reinstalling generates the necessary keys.

Answer (score 8):

To enable SSH server, you can try opening up a terminal window and typing the following command:

`sudo service ssh enable`

and then SSH server should be enabled on restart.

Comment: Do not recommend using `service` instead of `systemctl`. This option applies only to systems with `systemd`.

Comment: Yup, you're right, and I do think that sempaiscuba does provide a better answer than mine.

Comment: Correcting your question means changing it to the same what is already in the other upvoted question. Yes, Ubuntu 16 comes with systemd and you recommend using the old-school `service`.

Answer (score 3):

Try running these 2 commands which should enable ssh:

```
sudo systemctl enable ssh
sudo service ssh restart
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure openssh-server
```